# Pain at the back of the left Knee

Tags: knees

I happened to run on a uneven terrain (about a half a mile), from then on I am experiencing some pain in the back of my left knee when **raised to my chest folded**

Could anyone please suggest some stretching exercises?

Answer (score 2):

You should go to a doctor for a good diagnose. Internet is not realy the way to go here...
But when I read your symptoms I would guess it could be a little fracture in the back of your knee jointcapsle. This injury happens quickly when you run on rough terrain.
If that is the case then you should be resting because stretching will not help.... SEE A DOCTOR.